# Spatialite KNN view in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite, spatial-view, spatialite-gui, knn

My task is to calculate the average ground survey level for each tree in my dataset, using the 3 closest survey points (optionally within a 3m radius of the tree). I want to write this in a Spatial VIEW (or a table with triggers) so that any time I add a new tree (or new survey points, though that's unlikely) the values update themselves.

Here is the core of my `VirtualKNN() CREATE` statement to show what I'm getting at, minus the 3m radius:

```
CREATE view tree_avglev_k AS 
SELECT
   t.geometry AS geometry,
   t.pk_uid AS pk_uid,
   t.treeid AS treeid,
   AVG(l.lvl) AS avg_lvl 
FROM
   (SELECT
         k.*,
         t.pk_uid 
      FROM
         knn k,
         trees t 
      WHERE
         f_table_name = 'levels' 
         AND ref_geometry = t.geometry)
   a 
   LEFT JOIN
      levels l 
      ON (l.ogc_fid = a.fid) 
   LEFT JOIN
      trees t 
      ON (t.pk_uid = a.pk_uid) 
GROUP BY
   a.pk_uid 
ORDER BY
   t.treeid
```

But as of Jan 2018 QGIS 2.99/3 still does not support the `VirtualKNN()` function in Spatialite 4.4.0, so it can't process the information (see [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17742))

Is there some other more efficient way to work around this (without using PostGIS/any other client-server database)?

---

**What I have tried** (as reference):

I have a [long, ugly alternative](https://paste.ee/p/DwVjP) using `PtsDistWithin()` and Virtual Index. It's not the most efficient (still new to SQL) but on ~500 trees and ~5000 survey points, it loads in about 2 seconds in spatialite-gui (bit slower than the `VirtualKNN()` query)

But when loading it in QGIS it is *particularly* slow - and buggy (despite selecting unique integer column in DB Manager, it loads the geometry but won't load attributes). When I add other constraints (like using only levels within a certain area, again using VirtualIndex) it's practically unloadable.

Maybe I need a different approach (e.g., create normal view with just data, join to geometry separately)

---

However the main thrust of the question is not so much to fix my alternative approach, but to ideally find a solution as concise and zippy as `VirtualKNN()` for QGIS.

Comment: 11 months later, QGIS 3.4 still hasn't incorporated spatialite 4.4.0... :(

Comment: it would be a good thing to update spatialite in QGIS also because we are at version 5.0
https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook-5/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what the latest released version is.  From the home[0] and download 
page it looks like it's 4.3.0a - for the others there are only RCs or betas.

Jürgen E. Fischer

[0] https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=SpatiaLite
[1] http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/?C=M;O=D

--
qgis-developer: 
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-support-for-SpatiaLite-gt-4-5-td5393755.html